# How to add pictures to navigation bars on the tab bar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have my TabBar set up and I set the tab bar to this

[image]

Then it just looks like this

[image]

And yes i have a picture named info.

Here is the info image. Its named info.png

[image]

Comment: can you add info image here.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the info image is included in the target you are building by selecting the file in the project navigator in the left-hand sidebar and looking at the targets in the file inspector in the right-hand sidebar.

Check that the case is correct - `info.png` and `Info.png` are different when running on iOS.

Comment: Im pretty sure its in the targets, how do i put it in?

Comment: Make sure the target is ticked in Target Memberships.

Comment: "Doing a code for it" is completely uninformative.  If you solved your problem, post it as an answer so that anybody else who has a similar problem and finds this question will be helped.